# How do I basically pass a PHP array into a JS array - Laravel 5?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, laravel

I have a PHP array `dd($iperfProfiles);`

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => "ipv6-udp-upload"
]
```

Trying to access it in JS

I've tried

```
var iperfProfiles = "{{ json_encode($iperfProfiles) }}";
console.log(iperfProfiles);
return false;
```

I get

```
IPERF:1699 [&quot;ipv6-udp-upload&quot;]
```

How do I basically turn a PHP array into a JS array ?

Comment: You have to print it without escaping the output, by using `var iperfProfiles = {!! json_encode($iperfProfiles) !!};` - There's also a JSON blade directive `var iperfProfiles = @json($iperfProfiles);` which is probably your best bet.

Comment: var iperfProfiles = {!! json_encode($iperfProfiles) !!}; no quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//in PHP 
$iperfProfiles = json_encode($iperfProfiles);

//and then in JS
var iperfProfiles = JSON.parse({!!$iperfProfiles!!});
```

Comment: Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\json_string()

Comment: That was just a typo, wo sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

just use @json blade directive and pass raw php data to it without encoding it JSON.

**in blade template:**

```
const profiles = "@json($profiles)"
```

Answer (score 1):

try with just removing quotes

```
var iperfProfiles = {{ json_encode($iperfProfiles) }};
console.log(iperfProfiles);
```